# Design many-to-many join table with additional column

Tags: postgresql, database-design, many-to-many

I have `product` and `documentation` tables and want to hava a many-to-many relationship between them with an additional condition.

The tables look like this:

```sql
create table product (
  id bigserial primary key
);

create table documentation (
  id bigserial primary key,
  type text not null
);
```

And condition is: each product can have any number of documentation but no more than 1 of each type.

Is it possible to create such a constraint without addading a `type` column into the join table?

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way to do this is to bring in the `type` column into the join table.

First add a unique key across `id, type`

```sql
alter table documentation
  add unique (id, type);
```

Then create a join table. This will have a foreign key to that unique key. It will also have a primary key across the three columns, and a unique key across `product_id, type`.

```
create table product_documentation (
  product_id bigint not null references product (id),
  documentation_id bigint not null,
  type text not null,
  foreign key (documentation_id, type) references documentation (id, type),
  primary key (product_id, documentation_id, type),
  unique (product_id, type)
);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/kCI6H5E2)

---

In SQL Server, which supports indexed views, you can use an indexed view to enforce the constraing instead. Note that this is not the same as a materialized view in Postgres and Oracle.

```
create table product_documentation (
  product_id bigint not null references product (id),
  documentation_id bigint not null references documentation (id),
  primary key (product_id, documentation_id)
);
```

```
create view dbo.product_documentationType
with schemabinding
as

select
  pd.product_id,
  d.type
from dbo.product_documentation pd
join dbo.documentation d on d.id = pd.documentation_id;
```

```
create unique clustered index ucx on dbo.product_documentationType
  (product_id, type);
```

However the benefit of doing so as opposed to the above design is questionable.

Answer (score 0):

> I have `product` and `documentation` tables and want to have a many-to-many relationship between them ...

Actually, what you describe is a many-to-many relationship between product and type, documentation being an attribute of the link table (which may also be named "documentation").

A minimal implementation in modern Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
  prod_id bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
-- more 
);

CREATE TABLE prod_type (
  prod_type text PRIMARY KEY
-- more ?
);

CREATE TABLE documentation (
  prod_id bigint REFERENCES product
, prod_type text REFERENCES prod_type
, documentation text  -- NOT NULL ?
, PRIMARY KEY (prod_id, prod_type)
);
```

This way, a product can have one documentation per existing type.

If product types are lengthy strings, consider a surrogate PK for the `prod_type` table and use that as FK reference.

If you don't enforce `NOT NULL` for `documentation.documentation`, then you allow to link a product to a type without providing actual documentation. This may or may not be desirable. (Think of transient states.) All other columns in my schema are `NOT NULL` implicitly.

If the same documentation is applicable to multiple product/type combinations, break out documentation into its own table. The link table then implements a ternary relationship with an added `doc_id` (and a different table name, obviously), but still only `(prod_id, prod_type)` is unique - can be the PK.

Use descriptive names. "type" and "id" are too ambiguous for my taste - "id" being a wide-spread anti-pattern.

Basics:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9790225/939860)

About `IDENTITY`:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875517/939860)

Comment: But how would you associate `documentation` with multiple `product`?

Comment: This assumes the same documentation is only applicable to a single product/type combination. Else my model is not a good fit.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I like to be able to change type of an exisitng document?  That's a reason I'm look for a constaint and not to make it part of PK.

Comment: @abobov Perhaps you can clarify: you want to be able to change the type of an existing document? What happens if an associated product already has a document of that new type?

Comment: @Charlieface If an associated product already has a document of that new type - update should fail.

Comment: @abobov: A PK is just another constraint. you can change the type freely as long as that doesn't violate any of the constraints - like conflicting with an existing product/type combination.